# Add custom target to Android SDK and AVD Manager

Tags: android, sdk

From the Android SDK and AVD Manager it is possible to add an extra Add-on Site URL.

I'd like to have some starting point or documentation about developing and distributing add-ons so I can distribute an SDK for my own target device.

Comment: I found some information by browsing trough the source code from the SDK.

Comment: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/sdk.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar question that directed me to the [platform/vendor/samples](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/vendor/sample.git) folder of the Android source. The samples folder also contains some documentation.

Comment: The similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100592/android-sdk-add-on

Comment: The (minimal) documentation of the sample: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/vendor/sample.git;a=blob_plain;f=frameworks/PlatformLibrary/README.txt;hb=HEAD

Comment: It seems that the Android SDK Manager does not remember added custom Add-on Sites. I submitted a bug in the issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11313

Comment: Also a good reference for creating a repository.xml is the XSD that is used by the Android SDK Manager to check the XML: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/sdk.git;a=blob_plain;f=sdkmanager/libs/sdklib/src/com/android/sdklib/repository/sdk-repository-2.xsd;hb=HEAD

Comment: vendor/sample moved to here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/vendor/sample/+/master